# True type font creation for Urdu in Linux

Tags: linux, truetype-fonts

I am doing a project on Urdu OCR. To the simplest, I first want to create my own true type font for Urdu. Then, I want to build a text file using my Own font and convert it into image. After that I want to apply my OCR algorithm for the resultant image using my own created ttf file as a template. Can anyone help me for how to create ttf files in linux for Urdu and how to use them to create text. Any open source available for this like font lab software.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/). From its web page:

> FontForge -- An outline font editor that lets you create your own postscript, truetype, opentype, cid-keyed, multi-master, cff, svg and bitmap (bdf, FON, NFNT) fonts, or edit existing ones. Also lets you convert one format to another. FontForge has support for many macintosh font formats.

Comment: +1, this program is ugly in the outside and beautiful in the inside :)

Comment: Remember to use the proper Code Points for Urdu when crafting the font.